# iOS Notification Center Registration

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, uikit, apple-push-notifications

I want to make a game that tests out local notifications. In iOS 8, the code involves these steps:

1. Make a `UIMutableUserNotificationCategory` object that is the category of custom actions you want to implement.
2. Make up to 4 custom actions by using `UIMutableUserNotificationAction` instances.
3. Call `setActions:forContext:` to set up custom actions.
4. Make a `UIUserNotificationSettings` object and call `settingsForTypes:categories:` on it.
5. Register the application's user notification settings by calling `registerUserNotificationSettings:` on the shared `UIApplication` instance.

My question is, for the `UIUserNotificationSettings` mentioned in Step 4, how would you register an application for more that one category? The values that can be set for it are:

- `UIUserNotificationTypeAlert` (show just the alert)
- `UIUserNotificationTypeBadge` (show just a badge)
- `UIUserNotificationTypeSound` (only play a sound)
- `UIUserNotificationTypeNone` (do nothing)

It sounds like an application should be easily able to show an alert, display a badge, and display a sound. However, before the notification fires, it has to be registered for all of the three. The parameter takes an `NSUInteger`.

My question is, how would one make it so it had access to all three of the permissions? You can't pass an `NSArray` to it, so there should be another way I'm not seeing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take this as an example:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

Answer (score 1):

Take this as an example of how to add multiple categories

```
UIUserNotificationSettings* notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];
```

Comment: Thank you! Bit of a weird syntax, considering that returns an `NSUInteger`, but I guess the "OR" operator applies here.